# How to exit Do While loop when specific data entered?

Tags: excel, vba

The do while loop below is not exiting the loop when I want it to.

I want the loop to end once either a P or p is entered.

```
Private Sub btnDoWhile_Click()

    Dim product2 As String

    With wsLoops

        Do While product2 <> "P" Or product2 <> "p"
        product2 = Left(InputBox("Please enter product number", "Product please", "Enter product number here"), 1)
            If product2 = "P" Or product2 = "p" Then
                MsgBox "Thank you"
            ElseIf product2 = "" Then
                Exit Sub
            Else
                MsgBox "Please enter a valid product number"
            End If
        Loop

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the point of the `With`?

Comment: Please remove  `Or product2 <> "p"` in the ` Do While`

Comment: You are using `<>` *Not Equal To*. You want an `AND` here. `product2 <> "P" AND product2 <> "p"` Otherwise this will always pass because it can never be both `"P"` and `"p"`.

Comment: You could put `Exit Do` after `MsgBox "Thank you"`

Comment: Thank you! The and was what I was missing

Comment: To be clear the `Exit Do` is only a bandaid. The code is confusing at best due to what @JNevill pointed out. Writing it to make it clearer will help everyone in the long run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is ..... possible solution

```
Private Sub btnDoWhile_Click()
Dim product2 As String

With wsLoops
    Do
        product2 = Left(InputBox("Please enter product number", "Product please", "Enter product number here"), 1)
        If product2 = "P" Or product2 = "p" Then
            MsgBox "Thank you"
        ElseIf product2 = "" Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
            MsgBox "Please enter a valid product number"
        End If
    Loop While Not product2 = "P" And Not product2 = "p"
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I've never tried using while not but it makes a lot of sense

Comment: @financedude, my pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify the logic in this way (as well as others).

```
Private Sub btnDoWhile_Click()

    Dim product2 As String

    Do

        product2 = Left(InputBox("Please enter product number", "Product please", "Enter product number here"), 1)

        If LCase$(product2) = "p" Then
            MsgBox "Thank you"
        ElseIf product2 = "" Then
            Exit Sub
        Else
            MsgBox "Please enter a valid product number"
        End If

     Loop Until LCase$(product2) = "p"

End Sub
```